# How to write optional parameter in $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used $.getJSON to retrieve the data from my database. If the parameter dID is not null, then there is one parameter like :

```
$.getJSON(urlGetProByDep, { depID: dID }, function (data) {
   //blah blah blah                    
});
```

But if both dID and cID are not null so the function will use 2 parameter as below :

```
 $.getJSON(urlGetProByDep, { depID : dID,catID : cID }, function (data) {
   //blah blah blah                    
 });
```

Could anyone tell me how can I change the paramter in {....} due to the value of dID and cID.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {};
if(dID) {
    data.depID = dID;
}
if(cID) {
    data.catID = cID;
}

$.getJSON(urlGetProByDep, data, function (data) {
   //blah blah blah                    
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it error : "Invalid Object initializer". Expected ':'

Comment: Any solution please ThiefMaster.

Comment: Well why not link to the page with the error or show the line where it occurs. The code I posted does not cause such an error!

Comment: Uhhh so sorry, my bad. I forget to chage from {data} to data. After I changed, It works well. Thanks so much.

Comment: But if I have no any data to pass, and then the data have is empty(), so how could we do that?

Comment: Passing an empty object is perfectly fine.